# Is there any reason why this code wouldn't update my database?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Trying to run an update call on mongoDB, but when I try and do so, said database isn't updated. Any help here?

The database doc we are trying to edit is in the form of:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d5f7eb604eb380b0d8d8dd"), "student_id" : 1, "scores" : [ { "type" : "exam", "score" : 79.51115675153915 }, { "type" : "quiz", "score" : 93.5960500282434 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 10.051101066555079 }, { "type" : "homework", "score" : 17.8164864139428 } ], "class_id" : 176 }
```

And the command being run is:

```
db.grades.update
(
    {
        $and: 
            [
                {"class_id": 176},
                {"student_id": 1}
            ]
    },
    {
        $push:
        {
            scores:
            {
                "type": "extra credit",
                "score": 10
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your update query, why is `scores` not in double quotes?

Comment: It is working, https://mongoplayground.net/p/fUbiYF62BVF. make sure you are updating the correct db/collection.